# Compile with a list as an argument

Tags: compile

This is probably trivial, but I couldnt make it work:

```
safeConv = Compile[{{a, _Complex, 10}, {b, _Real}},
   If[b > 1, a[[1]], 0]
   ];
```

I get a rank-error

> Compile::cif: The types of the two results in If[b>1,a[[1]],{0}] are incompatible because their ranks are different. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>

I tried surrounding the 0 (else value) with curly brackets {0} and I even tried this

```
c = {0};
safeConv = Compile[{{a, _Complex, 10}, {b, _Real}},
   If[b > 1, a[[1]], c[[1]]]
   ];
```

but I still get the same error. Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: I want the first argument to be a 10 element list (vector). if `b > 1` then return the first element of `a`, else return 0

Answer (score 16):

I think this is because `a` in your code represents a rank 10 tensor.

If you want to use `a` as a vector, then I think it would be

```
 safeConv =Compile[{{a, _Complex, 1}, {b, _Real}}, If[b > 1, a[[1]], 0]]
```

Otherwise, if `a` is a rank 10 tensor, then something like this

```
safeConv = 
 Compile[{{a, _Complex, 10}, {b, _Real}}, If[b > 1, a[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], 0]]
```